# Не выходит сохранить файл в постоянном котологе

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Гитарные войны</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Гитарные войны.<br>Добавь свой рейтинг.
<?php
define('GW_UPLOADPATH', 'images/');
require_once ("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];
$screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
if(!empty($name) && !empty($score)) {
$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .GW_UPLOADPATH;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'],"$target")){
  $zero = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
  $query = "INSERT INTO guitarwars VALUES (0, NOW(),'$name','$score','$screenshot')";
  $result = mysqli_query($zero,$query);

  echo '<p>Спасибо за то, что добавили свой рейтинг!</p>';
  echo '<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ' . $name. '<br>';
  echo '<strong>Рейтинг:</strong> ' . $score . '<p>';
  echo '<img src="'.GW_UPLOADPATH.$screenshot.'"
      alt="Изображение, подтверждающее подлинность изображения"><br />';
  echo '<p><a href="index.php"> &lt;&lt; Назад к списку рейтингов</a></p>';
  $name = "";
  $csore = "";
  $screenshot = "";
  mysqli_close($zero);
  }
  }
 }


?>
<hr />
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" active="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" >
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32786" />
  <label for="name">Имя: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"
    value="<?php if(!empty($name)) echo $name; ?>" /><br/>
  <label for="score">Рейтинг: </label>
  <input type="text" id="score" name="score"
    value="<?php if(!empty($score)) echo $score ?>" />
  <label for="screenshot">Имя файла: </label>
  <input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot"
    value="<?php if(!empty($screenshot)) echo $screenshot ?>" />
    <hr />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Включение в партию" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: у вас множество стилистических ошибок помимо той с которой вы столкнулись. почитайте про sql-инъекции, у вас она есть, вам нужно использовать pdo. почитайте про разницу одинарных и двойных кавычек в php, в куске ...,"$target")... кавычки вообще не нужны. почитайте про то как подключать html шаблоны в php. это на будущее, а по поводу проблемы - опишите в вопросе какая ошибка у вас возникает, проблема может быть в чем угодно.

Comment: `$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .GW_UPLOADPATH;` и след строка $dir превращается в $target - магия?